# EF 7 Validation: EF not validating Required setting on property when using fluent statements in model builder

Tags: entity-framework

Using the verion of EF 7 provided with VS 2015 RC, my datacontext is not properly validating the "required" setting when I set it in the OnModelCreating()

Here is the code in my DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region Member
            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                            .ForRelational()
                            .Table("Member", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Key(x => x.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Index(x => x.UserName)
                        .Unique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.UserName)
                        .Required();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Index(x => x.Moniker)
                        .Unique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.Moniker)
                        .MaxLength(128)
                        .Required();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Index(x => x.Email)
                        .Unique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.Email)
                        .Required();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.Email)
                        .MaxLength(256);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.LastName)
                        .MaxLength(256);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.FirstName)
                        .MaxLength(256);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.Middle)
                        .MaxLength(256);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
                        .Property(x => x.ConcurrencyStamp)
                        .ConcurrencyToken()
                        .StoreComputed();
            #endregion

            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberRole>()
                        .Key(k => new
                                {
                                    k.MemberId,
                                    k.RoleId
                                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberRole>()
                        .ForRelational()
                        .Table("MemberRole", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberRole>()
                        .Property(x => x.ConcurrencyStamp)
                        .ConcurrencyToken()
                        .StoreComputed();

            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberRole>()
                        .Reference(m => m.Member)
                        .InverseCollection(x => x.Roles)
                        .ForeignKey(x=>x.RoleId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberRole>()
                        .Reference(m => m.Role)
                        .InverseCollection(x => x.Members)
                        .ForeignKey(x => x.MemberId);

            #region Role

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                        .Key(k => k.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                        .ForRelational()
                        .Table("Role", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                        .Property(x => x.ConcurrencyStamp)
                        .ConcurrencyToken()
                        .StoreComputed();

            //modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            //          .Collection(r=>r.Members)
            //          .InverseReference(m=>m.Role).ForeignKey(x=>x.RoleId);



            #endregion

            #region MemberClaim
            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberClaim>()
                .Key(k=>k.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberClaim>()
                        .ForRelational()
                        .Table("MemberClaim", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<MemberClaim>()
                        .Reference(c => c.Member)
                        .InverseCollection(m => m.Claims)
                        .ForeignKey(c=>c.MemberId);

            #endregion

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

I am attempting to do the database first option for "code first" which I have been using for some time now since it first came out and have not had this issue before.

Here is my data table in SQL:

```
USE [Fambase]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Member]    Script Date: 5/17/2015 11:59:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Moniker] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Middle] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsArchived] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateTimeDeleted] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateTimeArchived] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [DeletedBy] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [ArchivedBy] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Member] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Member] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Member_Id]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

If I remove the allow null setting on SQL server, EF does not evaluate it at all.  With NO NULL set I get the SQL error you would expect from SQL, but EF does not catch it and throw its on exception.

This does not seem like it is as intended.

**UPDATE** My base class is as follows

```
public class MemberBase : IMemberBase
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string Moniker { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Middle { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
        public Guid? SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    }
```

The entity inherits from the base class like so:

```
public class Member : MemberBase, IMember
    {
        #region IAuditable
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
        public string ArchivedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTimeModified { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTimeDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTimeArchived { get; set; }
        public byte[] ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Navigation 
        public virtual ICollection<ExternalLogin> ExternalLogins { get; set; } = new List<ExternalLogin>();
        public virtual ICollection<MemberClaim> Claims { get; set; } = new List<MemberClaim>();
        public virtual ICollection<MemberRole> Roles { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Is that code generated from reverse engineering? Shouldn't need 3 separate ModelBuilder statements for email field although I wouldn't think that would matter. What does the model look like?

Comment: Added the model definitiions.  I am doing everything manually at the moment because I am doing it in incremental steps.  You are probably right about not needing 3 separate email entries, but agree it should not matter.  I did not have this problem with EF 6 that I remember.  I was hoping to have some input before I submitted it as a bug.